# Do not delete ptr when momery is used by other objects

Tags: c++, pointers

I created `ABC` class and created its three objects by normal, assign and copy constructor. Now they are use same memory address for `ptr`.

When these objects are deleted means coming out of scope then first object deleted, but for second it is give error that memory is already deleted.
This is fine. that I understand.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class ABC
{
    private:
        int a;
        int *ptr;

    public:
        ABC();                      // Simple constructor.
        ABC(int a, int b);          // Parameterized constructor.
        ABC(const ABC &obj);        // Copy constructor.
        ~ABC();                     // Destructor.
        void display();             // Display.
        ABC& operator=(const ABC &obj); // Operator Overload.
};


ABC::ABC() 
{

}


ABC::ABC(int a, int b) 
{
    cout << "Parameterized constructor" << endl;
    // allocate memory for the pointer;
    this->a = a;   
    ptr = new int;
    ptr = &b;
}


ABC::ABC(const ABC &obj) 
{
    cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
    a = obj.a;
    //ptr = new int;
    //*ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
    ptr = obj.ptr; 
}


ABC& ABC :: operator=(const ABC &obj) 
{
    cout <<"Assignemnt operator overload"<<endl;
    this->a = obj.a;
    this->ptr = obj.ptr;
    return *this;
}


ABC::~ABC(void) 
{
   cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
   delete ptr;
}


void ABC::display() {
    cout << "a value = : " << a <<endl;
    cout << "ptr value = : " << ptr <<endl;
    cout << "*ptr value = : " << *ptr <<endl;
}


int main()
{
    // Normal.
    ABC obj1(1, 2);
    cout << "Point Obj1 value = : "<<endl;
    obj1.display();

    cout<<"\n\n";
    // Assignment.
    ABC obj2;
    obj2 = obj1;
    cout << "Point Obj2 value = : "<<endl;
    obj2.display();

    cout<<"\n\n";
    // Copy constructor.
    ABC obj3(obj1);
    cout << "Point Obj3 value = : "<<endl;
    obj3.display();

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do it that, I do not want to delete memory when other objects are using. How to handle this by Smart Pointer, I not want to do by in-build sheared pointer. I want to write Smart Pointer class and increase ptr reference count when other objects use same memory. But do not know how to do.

```
class SmartPointer
{

    public:
        int *ptr;
        int ref;
        SmartPointer();
        SmartPointer(int *p);
        int& operator *();
        ~SmartPointer();
};

SmartPointer::SmartPointer()
{
    cout<<"SmartPointerInitilaize default"<<endl;
    ref = 1;
}


SmartPointer::SmartPointer(int *p)
{
    cout<<"SmartPointerInitilaize para"<<endl;
    ptr = p;
    ref = 1;
}

int& SmartPointer:: operator *()
{  
    return *ptr; 
}

SmartPointer::~SmartPointer()
{

    cout<<"SmartPointer De-Initilaize"<<endl;
    //delete ptr;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you want to invent wheel once again.
To achive what you want:
first of all, ref counter need be static
second, increment it in constructor and decrement in destructor
thrid, when ref counter reach 0 in destructor u need to free your pinter.

have a nice day

Comment: Add a `static` reference counter and don't forget to lock it with a mutex or something when used in a multithreading enviroment.

Comment: who to use `static` for counting? means I want to increase ref count when object is create by assign or copy constructor.

Comment: You can do that with `static` ref variable. Only beware that it is then common for all the instances of the shared pointer (i.e. you cannot have two different instances and pass them around independently).

Comment: **Don't** add a static reference counter. That's just plain wrong. The common solution is to just `new` a counter. This counter is `delete`'d when it reaches 0.

Answer (score 2):

What you basically want to do is to implement a `std::shared_ptr`. You shouldn't do it normally, because it is quite tricky, however for educational purposes and to understand how that works:

1) The ref count needs to be part of the pointer data passed around (if not static), shared by all the "linked" `SmartPointer` instances.

2) You still need to define the copy constructor/assignment operator to increase the reference count. And in the destructor you decrease the refcount, and if zero, delete the pointer (and the extra data).

An example:

```
class SmartPointer
{

   struct Data {
        Data(int *p)
            : ptr(p)
            , ref(1)
        {}
        ~Data() {Release();}
        void Acquire() {
            ++ref;
        }
        void Release() {
            if (!--ref) { delete ptr; delete this; }
        }
        int *ptr;
        int ref;
   };

        Data *data;
    public:
        SmartPointer()
            : data(new Data(NULL))
        {}
        SmartPointer(int *p)
            : data(new Data(p))
        {}
        SmartPointer(const SmartPointer& x)
            : data(x.data)
        { data->Acquire(); }
        SmartPointer& operator =(const SmartPointer& x)
        {
            if (this != &x) {
                data->Release();
                data = x.data;
                data->Acquire();
            }
        }
        int& operator *() { return *data->ptr; }
        ~SmartPointer() { data->Release(); }
};
```

Note that this is very simplified (e.g. not thread safe), just the basic idea.

The actual std or boost shared_ptr is much more complicated (templated, supports custom deleter which involves type erasure etc.).

Comment: `data(new Data(p))` I am not getting this.

Comment: That creates data containing the pointer and the reference count **shared between all instances of the smart pointer**. This is essential for the shared pointer to work properly (so that all reference counts in all the shared instances will be the same).

Answer (score 1):

Add shared_level integer in SmartPointer

```
class SmartPointer{

public:
    int *ptr;
    int ref;
    int shared_level;
    SmartPointer();
    SmartPointer(int *p);
    int& operator *();
    ~SmartPointer(); 
};
```

Whenever the abc constructor is calling. Increment shared_level by 1. When ever  deconstructor calls, Decrement it by 1.
And While deconstructing check for SmartPointer->shared_level value, And if it is 1. Delete pointer, else just decrements is enough.

Note : Better use locks for sharePointer, If u want to access in multiple threads.

Comment: This way if copied between multiple instances the `ref` or `shared_level` values will drift apart. Therefore the reference data need to be shared between all the SmartPointer instances. You can somehow manage to keep the ref in sync between two instances, but even then in the destructor each instance will have its own value (which will be 2 for both instances), and will only decrement once (does not know about all the other instances), so the pointer will be never freed.

Comment: _destructor each instance will have its own value (which will be 2 for both instances), and will only decrement once (does not know about all the other instances), so the pointer will be never freed._




Deconstructor will be called for each of the object ( ABC ). R8 ?

Comment: Yes, and each of them will have ref count = 2 and decrement its own copy to 1, i.e. will not free the pointer. And if they both would have 1, both would free (= duplicate free = segfault).

Comment: I am not clear,
; While First ABC is initialised -> ref+1 = 2
; While Second ABC is initialised -> ref+1 = 3
;
; While Any Dectrctr -> ref-1 = 3-1 = 2 ---> Dont clear
; Another Object Decunstructor = 2-1 = 1 ---> Clear pointer

Comment: Right ... but what do you think would happen, if first object would go out of scope and the second and the third still were in use? They'll end up with a dangling pointer. With ref counted smart pointer the ptr should be deleted once the last instance goes out of scope, independent on the creation/destruction order. The fact that it will kind of work in this particular case is a pure coincidence (the first smart ptr instance is the owning one and by coincidence it is destroyed last).

Comment: We are passing pointer reference only r8 ? 
Is it problem cause any for 2nd & 3rd Objects ???? When the first object went out of scope .. Can't we access ? pointer object ( smart pinter ) from the reference passed.